Swiping Up, Down, Left, and Right in Java Android Studio
Hey I'm working in Java in Android Studio and I'm looking to create a button that can be swiped up, down, left, and right and have it be animated like the gmail archive or delete function on a phone. Anyone know how I might do this? Thanks in advance.
I tried doing this with recycler view, but I was only able to get to go left and right, not up and down. Additionally I felt like since I wasn't using the recycler view function, just the swiping left and right it didn't make much sense to use recycler view.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hope you find below link helpfull
swipe-gestures
It describes usage of Swipes from Up,Down,Right,Left
I did implement Swipe Gestures Left(Open File) and Right(Delete File) in My App inside RecyclerView Below is the Link if you want example and would be glad to share more info if required
My App Link(FileDownloader)
Below is the Code I implemented in my Project
Implemented Java Class
             // setting layout manager for our recycler view.

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper=new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
                itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(Rvadapter);
   
//Callback function for Swipe Implementation
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback=new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
            View view=viewHolder.itemView;

            Drawable icon= ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.delete);
            ColorDrawable bg;
            int iconRight=0,iconLeft=0,iconHeight= Objects.requireNonNull( icon).getIntrinsicHeight(),
                    iconWidth=icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),cellHeight=view.getBottom()-view.getTop(),
                    iconTop=view.getTop() + (cellHeight - iconHeight) / 2,
            iconBottom=iconTop+iconHeight, margin= convertDpToPx(context,32);

//Animation Setting on Swipe Gestures
            if(dX>0){   //Right Swipe
                icon=ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.open);
                bg=new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE);
                bg.setBounds(0,view.getTop(), (int) (view.getLeft()+dX),view.getBottom());
                iconLeft=margin;
                iconRight=margin+iconWidth;
            }else{     //Left Swipe
                icon= ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.delete);
                bg= new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
                bg.setBounds((int) (view.getRight()+dX),view.getTop(), view.getRight(),view.getBottom());
                iconLeft=view.getRight()- margin -iconWidth;
                iconRight=view.getRight()-margin;
            }
            bg.draw(c);

            icon.setBounds(iconLeft,iconTop,iconRight,iconBottom);
            icon.draw(c);
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX/4, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {


            switch (direction){
                case ItemTouchHelper.LEFT:
            //code to be executed on Left Swipe
                    viewHolder.itemView.invalidate(viewHolder.itemView.getLeft(),viewHolder.itemView.getTop(),0,viewHolder.itemView.getBottom());

                    break;

                case ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT:
                //code to be executed on Right Swipe
                    
viewHolder.itemView.invalidate(0,viewHolder.itemView.getTop(),viewHolder.itemView.getRight(),viewHolder.itemView.getBottom());

                    break;
            }
        }

    };


Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to do exactly what you do in your app with recycler view. That is, where as you swipe to the side you reveal a color with a symbol dysplaying the action you are about to take, but I would also like to do the same thing up and down. Do you know how to do this?

sorry i haven't implemented the Up and down functionality but if I found ! i would share the code with you by updating my original post.

ok, if you could that would be great

Hey OPerator, i shared a Sample Code above maybe try to modify them for your Requirements Accordingly. maybe try to use dY for change in Y-axis Direction and ItemTouchHelper.UP and ItemTouchHelper.DOWN for operations.If any questions notify me.
